# How to update d3.zoom pan boundaries with translateExtent dynamically (based on data)

Tags: d3.js

`getZoomFunc` function is run each time the data updates, to generate new coordinates to constrain the panning, but this does not work.

```
function getZoomFunc(data){   
  let minY = d3.min(data, d=>d.y)
  let maxY = d3.max(data, d=>d.y)
  let minX = d3.min(data, d=>d.x)
  let maxX = d3.max(data, d=>d.x)
 d3.zoom()
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [this.width, this.height],
    ])
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .translateExtent([
      [minX, minY],
      [maxX, maxY],
    ])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `d3.zoom()` function should only be called once.

You can use the `zoom.constrain` function to calculate the pan boundaries manually.

Then you have to set the min and max variables globally (or in the same scope) to be able to access them in the constrain function.

Default constrain function: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/main/README.md#zoom_constrain

Example:

```js
var minX, maxY, minY, maxY = 0;

function constrain(transform, extent, _translateExtent) {
    let dx0 = transform.invertX(extent[0][0]) - minX,
        dx1 = transform.invertX(extent[1][0]) - maxX,
        dy0 = transform.invertY(extent[0][1]) - minY,
        dy1 = transform.invertY(extent[1][1]) - maxY;
    return transform.translate(
        dx1 > dx0 ? (dx0 + dx1) / 2 : Math.min(0, dx0) || Math.max(0, dx1),
        dy1 > dy0 ? (dy0 + dy1) / 2 : Math.min(0, dy0) || Math.max(0, dy1)
    );
}

function calcExtent(data) {
    minY = d3.min(data, d => d.y);
    maxY = d3.max(data, d => d.y);
    minX = d3.min(data, d => d.x);
    maxX = d3.max(data, d => d.x);
}

const zoom = d3.zoom()
    .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [this.width, this.height],
    ])
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .constrain(constrain)
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

...
```

Each time your data is updated, call the `calcExtent` function and pass the data.